# How to create a custom “Customize” frontend in Oracle APEX 19+?

Tags: javascript, http, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

If you create an application with "Theme Style Selection" option and "Enable End Users to choose Theme Style" in User Interface Attributes, there's a "Customize" link in the footer, which is referenced by `#CUSTOMIZE#` substitution placeholder in the template, and the target is `javascript:apex.theme.openCustomizeDialog(title, language);`.

This function then opens a modal dialog (`apex.navigation.dialog`) with a `wwv_flow_customize.show` page using these parameters:

- `p_flow` - Application ID, returned by `$v('pFlowId')`
- `p_page` - Page ID, returned by `$v('pFlowStepId')`
- `p_session` - Session ID, returned by `$v('pInstance')`
- `p_lang` - Language two-letter code, from `openCustomizeDialog` argument

> This page could also be opened as standalone if you replace `/f?p=...` part with `/wwv_flow_customize.show?p_flow=...`

This page contains a form with radio group `name="p_themestyle"`. Labels of the options match with public Theme Styles, but the numeric multiple digit values don't match with Theme Style IDs from `wwv_flow_theme_styles` table.

What I need is a custom theme style switcher frontend. But I can't find the exact JS calls that set certain Theme Style IDs as selected for the current user. "Apply Changes" button just does `onclick="javascript:apex.submit('DOIT');"`. And the `desktop_all.min.js` file is very minified and obfuscated to properly debug.

I also wasn't able to track network activity in debugger as it always resets records after "Apply Changes".

- Is there an option somewhere to edit how the "Customize" page looks like?
- Is there full documentation for this feature somewhere?
- Where and how does APEX store which theme the current user has selected?
- What are the options to debug this request and find this particular API call in network activity?